# Replying to HR Email to include all accusations she pointed to me?

Tags: professionalism, ethics, human-resources

Still related to my previous [question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/91198/does-a-good-hr-yell-and-speak-loudly-about-employees-issue-in-public?noredirect=1#comment269289_91198), but now I am asking about a different issue.

The HR representative told me that she sent my manager and I an email asking about me, but I told her I didn't get it, so then she accused me that I deleted that email and many others.

While in fact, she **wrongly** sent the email to my personal email (it is used during recruitment process), not my work email.

I want to reply her email, but is it ok if I told everything there including all accusations since my manager is also in the loop **or just calmly reply her that she sent the email to wrong email address**?

I am not only considering my professionalism, ethic, but also my reputation in the company.

Comment: In what country is this in? What language is used in your company?

Comment: @StephanBranczyk LOL sorry for my bad English!

Comment: I don't understand your 4th paragraph. Definitely, reply to her that she used the wrong email address and that she should delete your personal email address from her address book and only use your work email from now on. You need to let HR and your boss know about this as quickly as possible. It seems you may have missed other emails from her because of this as well. This email snafu could be the root of many problems you have with this person.

Comment: Well, my question is it ok to counter her accusations in her email or is it better if I just reply her that she sent the email to my personal email so I never know the email.

Comment: Luckily this is the first time, but became the root cause of my yesterday issue.

Comment: Honestly, you're not that good of a writer. Plus, there is always the risk of incriminating oneself when replying to someone in writing. If I were you, I would respond to the accusations in person, but I would still correct the email address snafu by email.

Comment: Did she accuse you of that in front of someone or in private? If it's in private, answer in private. If it's in public, I'm then really surprised of what the hell kind of company that hires such a horrible HR person that is super-defensive.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk so is it better to respond her in person rather than in email for the accusations, even though she didn't want to hear me at all yesterday?

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist yeah, please find the related question link on my post above :)

Comment: @Lewis, Are those accusations serious? Do you think they could lead to your dismissal or to a demotion? Does this job earn you 75K or more per year? If so, it may be worthwhile for you to consult an employment lawyer and pay him to help you draft a response.

Comment: I think it's quite serious and may lead to dismissal since she told me want to tell it to highest boss. No only around 40K, since I am only a normal and non-executive staff.

Answer (score 8):

Reply in a calm manner. Any other manner would reflect badly on yourself and would not help the situation.

Start by apologising for the miscommunication (Even if it wasn't your fault, it just calms the situation down) and explain the situation. Also reply to the email that was sent to your personal email address. (Ensure you send from your work email).

Ensure you cc all relevant parties so they are in the loop. **Most importantly** request your personal email is removed from the system so a mishap like this will not happen again.

Doing so provides a solution, allowing all parties to move forward. Mistakes happen, there is little point escalating it further.

Answer (score -1):

I ve worked retail for years,and if I can tell you one thing its that  playing along with other people(apply to erratically behaved buyers,customer support for disgruntled, borderline unreasonable people etc) up to the point where you get what target you had in mind, is always the number one solution. Now consider this situation, you impulsively want to lash out to the HR rep which for some reason, justified or not is not relevant to the point, has/had issues with you. Yes you ll feel momentarily great but also yes, you ll setup yourself to make enemies outside of people that are supposed to be on the same team with you and look as someone that cant handle simple situations(imagine what implications this may have if you have to interact with clients as part of your job description or just about your potential to ascend the company leaderboard) to your manager by replying in a passive-aggressive or straight up offending way to the original offense.  So reply in a calm composited professional way(with your manager on CC) as if nothing had happened and let the fool look like one for not being able to even send a mail correctly and then even getting mad on something they caused.